# How do I get the SRP_A value when doing AdminInitiateAuth for CUSTOM_AUTH?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

My aws cognito setup is CUSTOM_AUTH. I already attached the lambda challenges in the settings. In the [param shape](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/admininitiateauthcommandinput.html#authparameters) of the AdminInitiateAuth... it says that if I want to start custom auth with password verification, I need to specify `ChallengeName: SRP_A` and `SRP_A: (The SRP_A Value)`.

Which I did as shown below:

```js
const command = new AdminInitiateAuthCommand({
  AuthFlow: 'CUSTOM_AUTH',
  AuthParameters: {
    USERNAME: username,
    CHALLENGE_NAME: 'SRP_A',
    SRP_A: '{SRP_A value}',
    SECRET_HASH: secretHash,
  },
  ClientId: clientId,
  UserPoolId: poolId,
});
```

Note that the docs says `ChallengeName: SRP_A` but that will throw error, it should be `CHALLENGE_NAME: 'SRP_A'`.

Also if I change the AuthFlow to `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH` and put `PASSWORD` in the params then the auth will be a success, but what I need is the `CUSTOM_AUTH`

I am using `@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider` library if that matters../

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following Library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-user-pool-srp-client

Install the library

```
npm install amazon-user-pool-srp-client --save
```

Import

```
import { SRPClient } from 'amazon-user-pool-srp-client'
```

Initialize SRPClient

```
  const userPoolId = process.env.CognitoUserPoolUsers.split('_')[1]
  const srp = new SRPClient(userPoolId)
```

Note: Your userpool ID in the environment variables should look like this `ap-southeast-1_9xxxxxxx`. i.e. the region and id with a underscore between them

Finally, generate SRP_A

```
const SRP_A = srp.calculateA()
```

BTW This library also has methods to help you generate the `TIMESTAMP` and `PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE` which might be helpful for the next `PASSWORD_VERIFIER` step for cognito SRP authentication

Comment: Ran into 'Incorrect username or password.' issue which is an open ticket in the mentioned package

Comment: Hi @AshwinChandran I am able to replicate that error (NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password) when the Cognito User Pool is incorrectly formatted. Just a pointer to double check:
In `const srp = new SRPClient(userPoolId);`, the `userPoolId` should be in `5HbFDz3pz` format (**without** the region prefix. i.e. `eu-west-2_5HbFDz3pz` will throw the error you mentioned)

Comment: Moved to another method, should help anyone else who comes across this. Thanks for replying!